# Java List of array repeating last object fecthed

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I'm trying to populate a list with a resultset from my database.  Thing is, the list is displaying only the last result recovered from db as soon as it gets out of the while() loop. The code:

```
public List<String[]> some_function(){
    List<String[]> trs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Connection conn = conectar_post("","","","");
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSetMetaData rmd = null;
    String sqls = "";

    sqls = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 LIMIT 4";

    try{ 
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sqls);
        rmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int i=0, ncol = 0, w=0;

        ncol = rmd.getColumnCount()+1;
        String[] line = new String[ncol];

        while(rs.next()){
            for(i=1;i<ncol;i++){
                line[i] = rs.getString(i);
            }
            trs.add(line);
            System.out.println(trs.get(w)[i-2]);
            w++;
        }

        System.out.println("> "+trs.get(1)[1]);
        System.out.println("> "+trs.get(2)[1]);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return trs;
}
```

The output:

```
244447
244448
244449
352712
> 352712
> 352712
```

There's something I'm missing?

Comment: `trs.add(line);` is always the same `String[]` object.

Comment: Have you done the appropriate debugging?

Comment: You should submit this to codereview.stackexchange.com as well, this code is really hard to read the way it tis...

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] line = new String[ncol];
```

should be inside `while(rs.next())`